# Is php's file_put_contents safe for concurrent reads from Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

Imagine an online newspaper with static files, like the first page with the headlines.
The index.html is generated by a PHP script run by cron every 5 minutes, and it writes the file on a volume shared with Nginx.
The script rewrites the index.html through `file_put_contents`. No other process modifies the file, while Nginx returns its content.

Taking into account multiple reading accesses on the `index.html` per second, would `file_put_contents` be safe? If not: what could I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isn't safe. Writing to files is not atomic. If nginx tries to read the file while the script is in the middle of generating it, it will get a partial file.

Do something like this:

```
file_put_contents("index.html.new", $new_contents);
rename("index.html.new", "index.html");
```

The rename will be atomic, so nginx will get either the old or new version, but never a partial file.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use symlinks, so index.html points to a eg index.html.20201215 and you just change that symlink after each file generation. This way you have a history of all the files.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea if you want to keep a history and be able to revert easily.

Comment: could the renaming fail in some way because of the concurrency?

Comment: No, there's no locking that prevents renaming.